# Is it by or from in "I love to wear shoes by Nike."

Tags: prepositions

> I love to wear shoes by Nike.

Instead of “by Nike” am I able to say “from Nike”?

If so, which one works better?

Comment: I'm sure Nike themselves would prefer you to use ***by** Nike*, because that's the preposition we use to talk about [*a work of art] **by** [an artist]*. It tends to imply *[artistically] **created by** the producer*, whereas ***from*** is much more likely to be used in "lowly, humdrum" contexts like *He wears cheap shoes **from** the local supermarket*.

Answer (score 1):

Both options are grammatically correct and get the meaning across, but neither is particularly idiomatic.

Usually you would only talk about wearing clothing (or shoes, in this case) *by* a brand if that brand is also the name of a fashion designer, such as Michael Kors or Vera Wang. As such, saying "shoes *by* X" implies that X is some luxury brand, so that doesn't really work in this case.

If you say "shoes *from* Nike", it sounds like Nike is the name of a store. While Nike does have their own shoe stores, you can also get Nike shoes at a bunch of other stores, and since what you really mean is that you like Nike-branded shoes and not that you like shoes that come specifically from Nike stores, this phrasing isn't the best.

The most idiomatic way to express your idea is to simply say "I love to wear Nike shoes."

You can also say "I love to wear Nikes."

Answer (score 0):

> I love Nike shoes.

> I love to wear shoes (designed/manufactured/sold) by Nike.

I don't think *wear* and *from* go well together. You might use *get* and *buy*, though.

> I **got** them (these shoes) **from** Nike.

> You can **buy** them **from** Nike for $X.